# Remove 'lesser' entries from array

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to prune some files I have. I'll save you the beast I've written so far and keep it simple by providing a fictional code.

Let's take this array:

```
[System.String[]]$Collection = 'Invitational.Gold.txt', 'Invitational.Bronze.txt', 'Invitational.Silver.txt', 'Olympics.Silver.txt', 'Olympics.Bronze.txt'
```

At this point, I need to do three things:

1. Group by the match type (*Invitational/Olympic*)
2. Sort by medal type in descending order of value (*gold/silver/bronze*)
3. Per match type, preserve the highest value medal, while deleting the others.

My first thought is to work some RegEx:

```
$Collection[0] -match '^(.+)\.(bronze|silver|gold).txt'
```

I'm using `[0]` here so I can test it without writing a foreach.

The above will store `Invitational` in `$Matches[1]` and `Gold` in `$Matches[2]`.

Now at this point, I could filter the `$Collection` by match type using a `Where-Object`. But then I'd run into problems during step 3. You see, if I used a foreach-construct, it would perform the `match` three times, finding the gold medal three times. And since it deleted the files the first time, it would generate errors during the second and third run.

So can somebody explain how I can do only a single lookup per match type? In other words:

1. It finds the first file: `Invitational.Gold`
2. It looks to see if there are other medals from `Invitational` and finds the silver and bronze files, which are deleted.
3. It moves on to the next file in memory, `Invitational.Bronze.txt`
   It looks to see if there are other medals from `Invitational` and finds the silver and gold files. It proceeds to try en delete bronze and silver again, resulting in errors because they were already deleted. And that is what I need to avoid but haven't been able to.

So how would I accomplish this while avoiding duplicating code blocks (re-writing the `$Collections` content after every action)?

The neatest solution I can think of is to somehow use Group-Object to create groups per match type, and then process every group only once. But I have no idea how to do that.

EDIT:
I'm thinking along these lines now:

```
$Result = $Collection | ForEach-Object -Process {
  $Null = $PSItem -match '^(.+)\.(bronze|silver|gold).txt'
  $Properties = @{
    'MatchType' = $Matches[1]
    'Object'    = $PSItem
  }
  New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property $Properties
}
$Result | Group-Object -Property MatchType
```

Now I have a grouping that I could work with. I think. I'll be patient and wait for better/other suggestions.

Comment: @Ansgar Wiechers
Since you removed PoSh from the title: when I google I always use "Powershell" and my search term together. Would search engines still find this post if I were to look for "powershell remove entries from array"? Or will it get lost amidst the JavaScript, Python and other posts I don't click on?
Also, with a 5854 score in PoSh, I'm sure you have ideas concerning this question?

Comment: I removed it from the subject, because the [general consensus](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19190) is that tags don't belong in the title. We have a "tags" section specifically for them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here's what i'm thinking. but there may  be a faster way... however repeating this specifically 100 times took 36 milliseconds total...

```
 [System.String[]]$Collection = 'Invitational.Gold.txt', 'Invitational.Bronze.txt', 'Invitational.Silver.txt', 'Olympics.Silver.txt', 'Olympics.Bronze.txt'

$collectionToOrder = $null
$collectionToOrder = foreach ($item in $Collection) {
$order = $null

    if ($item -match "Invitational") {$order = "1" }
    if ($item -match "Olympics") {$order = "2" }
    if ($item -match "Gold") {$order += "a" }
    if ($item -match "Silver") {$order += "b" }
    if ($item -match "Bronze") {$order += "c" }

    [pscustomobject] @{Order=$order
                       list=$Item
                                            }


}

$collectionOrdered = $collectionToOrder | sort -property order
Remove-Variable collectionToOrder 
$collectionToDelete = ($collectionOrdered | where order -Match "1")[1..5]
$collectionToDelete += ($collectionOrdered | where order -Match "2")[1..5]
foreach ($item in $collectionToDelete) {remove-item $item.list}
```

It could be reworked a tiny bit(depending on what output you want) but basically I made the first group of search requirements add a property named Order with a value of 1,2, etc... Then the next group added to that property a,b,c etc..  and you can keep going adding to the text. Meaning it could have a 3rd or 4th reason to add to order. and finally it sorts by the order. Issue is, if it finds different matching words, (silver.gold.Olympics for example) it will add to the order property funkily, but your example didn't have this as a possible concern.

Added another section to delete the files that are wrong. Mind you it deletes from the current working directory.

you could do something at the end like

```
foreach ($item in $collectionToDelete) {remove-item $folder\$item.list}
```

if you set a $folder variable at the top to be where you're working

Too late, i re-wrote it to work differently, and it doesn't care what words you use...

```
 [System.String[]]$Collection =  'Invitational.Bronze.txt', 'Invitational.Silver.txt',  'Invitational.Gold.txt', 'Olympics.Bronze.txt', 'Olympics.Silver.txt'

foreach ($item in $Collection) {
    if ($item -match "Silver") {
        remove-item $item.replace('.Silver.txt','.Bronze.txt')
    } 
}

foreach ($item in $Collection) {
    if ($item -match "Gold") {
        remove-item $item.replace('.Gold.txt','.Silver.txt')
        remove-item $item.replace('.Gold.txt','.Bronze.txt')
    }
}
```

This is getting long LOL... anyhow i took your answer, (Which is genius) and simplified it...

```
[System.String[]]$Collection = 'Invitational.Gold.txt', 'Invitational.Bronze.txt', 'Invitational.Silver.txt', 'Olympics.Silver.txt', 'Olympics.Bronze.txt', 'World.Open.Silver.txt'

$Collection | ForEach-Object -Process {
  If ($PSItem -match 'Silver') {
    $name = ($_ -split 'Silver') -join 'Bronze'
    If ($Collection -contains $name) { "Removing: $Name" }
  } # If 'Silver'
} # ForEach-Object

$Collection | ForEach-Object -Process {
  If ($PSItem -match 'Gold') {
      $name = ($_ -split 'Gold') -join 'Silver'
      If ($Collection -contains $name) { "Removing: $Name" }
      $name = ($_ -split 'Gold') -join 'Bronze'
      If ($Collection -contains $name) { "Removing: $Name" }
  } # If 'Gold'
} # ForEach-Object
```

Comment: My main problem here would be that I don't know the match types beforehand. In this case, it's `Invitational` and `Olympics`. But it could be one of many things. So I'm unable to specify the match type, all I can do is grab every file with identical match types, whatever they are, and bunch those together. Which is why I used RegEx to find everything that came before the medal type. I'll play around with this a bit, thanks!

Comment: This was the toughest of the three to make work, since I couldn't predict the number and names of the match types, but I made a working solution. From your style, I'd say PoSh is not your primary language. And this is definitely a very impressive usage of string manipulation. You're the only one that found a way to avoid `Group-By` and it ended up being a very elegant solution that taught me some new ways of using the pipeline. Thanks!

Comment: I don't really know languages. Lol. I know logic gates I suppose. Anyhow I'm glad it helped some. Sorry it wasn't the best option. I didn't realize you had other options. We could have searched for gold and deleted the rest based on the first word. Then searched for silver and deleted bronze. Lol. Want me to write it that way?

Comment: Hey, I loved your solution! I might still use it in other scripts. If you have the time, I always have room for something new. You can see what I did with it below. I would be curious how you would do it, especially since yours was the hardest one to make work. The medal is known to me, what comes before it isn't. Could be anything, but it's always something, never nothing. I added a "World.Open.Silver.txt" to the list to prevent splitting on the `.` while having only 1 item for that match.

Comment: I re-wrote a new method. Super simple. Straight forward, and logically sound.added it to my answer

Comment: I added a "World.Open.Silver.txt". No more splitting. :)

Comment: K i removed the split, and replaced it with replace. So now it doesn't matter how many words or dots are before the medal style.

Comment: I actually made that work in a few minutes and added it to my summary. What I learned about `.split()` vs. `-split` could replace that nasty `match`. I'll let it marinate for a while before closing out the question. Thanks a million!

Comment: i don't know all the differences, but -replace can handle regex where .replace can't.. Maybe split is the same. The issue with just straight out trying to get rid of a search function, still poses the threat of issues pertaining to a non-ordered list.

Comment: I read your tweak, and even simplified it further. Have a look :D  Also realized that a Silver may not exist but a Bronze and gold may, so i have Gold delete both just in case.

Comment: Very long, the powers that be will take notice, even though it is all about coming to the solution.
With your last edit, I figured that although `split/join` is fun, in this case we might as well go back to your earlier suggestion of just using `replace`. I also used an `elseif` to ensure that `gold` didn't remove `bronze` if `silver` already did so in the previous loop.
Although the actual problem I asked this question for won't be that easy,  you did end up with the best answer to this question. Simple, efficient and effective.

Comment: Ah shucks. I feel honored. A PoSH grandmaster such as yourself giving me reverence. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

To sort values specific way you would need to implement sort of an index.

```
$MedalValue = @{
    Gold = 3;
    Silver = 2;
    Bronze = 1;
}

[System.String[]]$Collection = 'Invitational.Gold.txt', 'Invitational.Bronze.txt', 'Invitational.Silver.txt', 'Olympics.Silver.txt', 'Olympics.Bronze.txt'

$DataSet = foreach ($Item in $Collection){
    $File = [regex]::Split($Item,'\.')
    New-Object PSObject -Property @{
        Type = $File[0];
        Medal = $File[1];
        Value = $MedalValue[$File[1]];
    }
}
$DataSet | Sort-Object @{expression='Type';Ascending=$true},@{expression='Value';Descending=$true} | Select-Object Type, Medal
```

Output:

```
Type         Medal 
----         ----- 
Invitational Gold  
Invitational Silver
Invitational Bronze
Olympics     Silver
Olympics     Bronze
```

Not sure if I completely understand your question. But if you want to get the top item for every type you could use selections and sortings like so:

```
$DataSet | 
    Group-Object Type | 
        ForEach-Object {
            $Name = $_.Name
            $DataSet | 
                Where-Object {$_.Type -eq $Name} |
                    Sort-Object -Property Value -Descending |
                        Select @{Label='Files';Expression={'{0}.{1}.txt' -f $_.Type,$_.Medal}} -First 1
        }
```

Output:

```
Files                 
----                 
Invitational.Gold.txt
Olympics.Silver.txt
```

Comment: The problem with splitting at the `.` is that there may be a match type that is composed of 2+ words, where the spaces have been replaced with dots. But that part is not the challenge for me.
This might work, although you gave yourself an extra level of complexity by re-assembling the filename, when you could have made it a third column in your `DataSet`. At least, that's what I think at first glance.
Then to delete low-valued files I'd have to use it the other way around by using `SkipLast` while sorting from low to high value.
The value-definition is nice, I can play with that. Thanks!

Comment: I was able to come up with a possible solution using the `Value`-index lesson you gave me to assign a numeric value to the medal type. Would not have come up with that myself. I'll try the others as well.

Answer (score 1):

i tried a slightly different way. [*grin*]

group by `$_.Split('.')[0]', check for gold/silver/bronze, then used an IF/ELSEIF to remove the items *after* the highest found.

this likely will need a check for the "to delete" files OR setting the cmdlet to ignore "not found" errors.

```
$Collection = @(
    'Invitational.Gold.txt'
    'Invitational.Bronze.txt'
    'Invitational.Silver.txt'
    'Olympics.Silver.txt'
    'Olympics.Bronze.txt'
    )

$GroupedCollection = $Collection |
    Group-Object {$_.Split('.')[0]}

foreach ($GP_Item in $GroupedCollection)
    {
    $Gold = $Silver = $Bronze = ''

    $Gold = $GP_Item.Group -match 'gold'
    $Silver = $GP_Item.Group -match 'silver'
    $Bronze = $GP_Item.Group -match 'bronze'

    if ($Gold)
        {
        Remove-Item -Path $Silver -WhatIf
        Remove-Item -Path $Bronze -WhatIf
        }
        elseif ($Silver)
        {
        Remove-Item -Path $Bronze -WhatIf
        }
    }
```

hope that helps,
lee

Comment: Wow, nice formatting, apart from the `elseif` that snuck in a few extra spaces. This could actually work, I think, although I would personally  replace the `if/elseif` with a `switch/continue` (I don't like an array of ifs). Your way of working with the grouping gives me something to experiment with. Thanks!

Comment: @Mark - yep, the `switch` statement makes for a very easy to read set of tests. since this was only two tests, i stuck with the old fashioned IF/ELSEIF structure. you are quite welcome ... glad to help a tad! [*grin*]

Comment: This one was a bit more challenging since I have to use the `-match` instead of a simple `-split` and as a result my `Group-Object` contained hash tables inside of arrays instead of just the filenames, so I needed to split those. Also, I needed to account for groups with only 1 file. But I got something that works, and you made me work with RegEx in a way I hadn't before. Thanks!

Comment: @Mark - the way PoSh handles `$Collection <-comparison operator>` is really odd ... and quit handy as long as you _expect_ it. [*grin*] you are most welcome! quite glad to have helped ... [*grin*]

Answer (score 0):

After working with each of the 3 answers given, I created a working solution in each case, trying to stay as close to the solution as possible while still applying it to my situation. These are what I came up with:

@Kirill Pashkov introduced the concept of weight/value that I found very interesting to work with:

```
[System.String[]]$Collection = 'Invitational.Gold.txt', 'Invitational.Bronze.txt', 'Invitational.Silver.txt', 'Olympics.Silver.txt', 'Olympics.Bronze.txt', 'World.Open.Silver.txt'

$Weight = @{
  'Gold'   = 1;
  'Silver' = 2;
  'Bronze' = 3;
} # Weight

$DataSet = $Collection | ForEach-Object -Process {
  $Null = $PSItem -match '^(.+)\.(bronze|silver|gold).txt'
  $Properties = @{
    'Type'   = $Matches[1]
    'Medal'  = $Matches[2]
    'Weight' = $Weight[$Matches[2]]
    'Name'   = $PSItem
  } # Properties
  New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property $Properties
} # ForEach-Object

$DataSet | Group-Object -Property 'Type' | ForEach-Object -Process {
  $PSItem.Group | Sort-Object -Property 'Weight' -Descending | Select-Object -SkipLast 1 | ForEach-Object -Process {
    Write-Output -InputObject ('Removing: {0}' -f $PSItem.Name)
  } # ForEach-Object
} # ForEach-Object
```

Output:

```
Removing: Invitational.Bronze.txt
Removing: Invitational.Silver.txt
Removing: Olympics.Bronze.txt
```

@Lee_Dailey managed to get the `Group-By` in a one-liner. I couldn't manage that, but I used the other answers to trim it down to three lines. I then had to re-structure the resulting table to filter the unwanted files by their string-values. And I had to avoid groups with only a single file in them. Using `break` I was able to prevent duplicate results from the `Switch`-statement:

```
[System.String[]]$Collection = @(
    'Invitational.Gold.txt'
    'Invitational.Bronze.txt'
    'Invitational.Silver.txt'
    'Olympics.Silver.txt'
    'Olympics.Bronze.txt'
    'World.Open.Silver.txt'
) # $Collection

$DataSet = $Collection | ForEach-Object -Process {
  $Null = $PSItem -match '^(.+)\.(bronze|silver|gold).txt'
  [PSCustomObject] @{'Type' = $Matches[1]; 'Object' = $PSItem}
}
$GroupedCollection = $DataSet | Group-Object -Property 'Type'

ForEach ($Grouping in $GroupedCollection) {
  If ($Grouping.Count -gt 1) {
    $GP_Item = [PSCustomObject]@{'Name' = $Grouping.Name; 'Group' = ($Grouping.Group | Select-Object -ExpandProperty 'Object')}

    Switch -Regex ($GP_Item.Group) {
      'gold' {
        "Keeping: $($GP_Item.Group -match 'gold')"
        "Removing: $($GP_Item.Group -match 'silver')"
        "Removing: $($GP_Item.Group -match 'bronze')"
        Break
      } # Gold
      'silver' {
        "Keeping: $($GP_Item.Group -match 'silver')"
        "Removing: $($GP_Item.Group -match 'bronze')"
        Break
      } # Silver
    } # Switch
  } # If
} # ForEach
```

Output:

```
Keeping: Invitational.Gold.txt
Removing: Invitational.Silver.txt
Removing: Invitational.Bronze.txt
Keeping: Olympics.Silver.txt
Removing: Olympics.Bronze.txt
```

Finally, @Robert Cotterman had an ingeneous solution using string manipulation and RegEx to get the desired result. I had to re-write to account for the match type being unknown, but managed to get it to work at the end with a lot of pipeline-usage:

```
[System.String[]]$Collection = 'Invitational.Gold.txt', 'Invitational.Bronze.txt', 'Invitational.Silver.txt', 'Olympics.Silver.txt', 'Olympics.Bronze.txt', 'World.Open.Silver.txt'

[System.Int16]$Count = 1
$MatchTypes = $Collection | ForEach-Object -Process {
  $Null = $PSItem -match '^(.+)\.(bronze|silver|gold).txt'
  $Matches[1]
} | Select-Object -Unique | ForEach-Object -Process {
  [PSCustomObject]@{'Name' = $PSItem; 'Order' = $Count}
  $Count += 1
}

$CollectionToOrder = ForEach ($Item in $Collection) {
  ForEach ($Type in $MatchTypes) { If ($Item -match $Type.Name) {[System.Int16]$Group = $Type.Order} }
  Switch -Regex ($Item) {
    'Gold'   { $Weight = 'a' }
    'Silver' { $Weight = 'b' }
    'Bronze' { $Weight = 'c' }
  } # Switch
  [PSCustomObject]@{ 'Group' = $Group; 'Weight' = $Weight; 'List' = $Item }
} # ForEach

$CollectionOrdered = $CollectionToOrder | Sort-Object -Property 'Group', 'Weight' -Descending
[System.Int16]$TypeCount = ($CollectionOrdered | Select-Object -Property 'Group' -Unique).Count
$CollectionToDelete = 1..$TypeCount | ForEach-Object -Process { $CollectionOrdered | Where-Object -Property 'Group' -Match $PSItem | Select-Object -SkipLast 1 }
$CollectionToDelete | ForEach-Object -Process { Write-Output -InputObject ('Removing: {0}' -f $PSItem.List) }
```

Output:

```
Removing: Invitational.Bronze.txt
Removing: Invitational.Silver.txt
Removing: Olympics.Bronze.txt
```

The one annoyance I had was that I couldn't convert my `-matches` line into a `[regex]::match` line, but that is another question. As is the fact that `[PSCustomObject]` is not the same as `[System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject]`

In the end, I'd probably go with @Kirill Pashkov's solution, since it seems to be the most elegant one and allows me to possibly fill the Weight-variable by means of CSV (although I'd need to manipulate the RegEx query as well then). So unless my answer is automatically selected as the accepted one, I'll likely choose his.

I lost half my weekend, but I learned a lot and can now go back to work on my fileserver-manipulation project. Thanks for the help, guys!

EDIT:

Props to @Robert Cotterman for coming up with a super-simple way of doing something I spent a full day on. Just goes to show it doesn't have to be complicated. I found out that the `split`-method splits on every occurrence of every character, but the `-split`-operator uses RegEx and can work on an entire word. With that in mind, as well as the possibility that there is something **after** the medal, I ended up with that instead of `replace` after all.

```
[System.String[]]$Collection = 'Invitational.Gold.txt', 'Invitational.Bronze.txt', 'Invitational.Silver.txt', 'Olympics.Silver.txt', 'Olympics.Bronze.txt', 'World.Open.Silver.txt'

$Collection | ForEach-Object -Process {
  If ($PSItem -match 'Silver') {
    $Split = $PSItem -split 'Silver'
    $Name = ('{0}Bronze{1}' -f $Split[0], $Split[1])
    If ($Collection -contains $Name) { "Removing: $Name" }
  } # If
} # ForEach-Object

$Collection | ForEach-Object -Process {
  If ($PSItem -match 'Gold') {
    $Split = $PSItem -split 'Gold'
    $Name = ('{0}Silver{1}' -f $Split[0], $Split[1])
    If ($Collection -contains $Name) { "Removing: $Name" }
  } # If
} # ForEach-Object
```

Output:

```
Removing: Invitational.Bronze.txt
Removing: Olympics.Bronze.txt
Removing: Invitational.Silver.txt
```

@Robert Cotterman's last edit helped me reconsider the `-replace`-operator. Also needed to use `elseif` to avoid a duplicate result during the second `ForEach` in the case that all three medals exist.

```
[System.String[]]$Collection = 'Invitational.Gold.txt', 'Invitational.Bronze.txt', 'Invitational.Silver.txt', 'Olympics.Silver.txt', 'Olympics.Bronze.txt', 'World.Open.Silver.txt'

$Collection | ForEach-Object -Process {
  If ($PSItem -match 'Silver') {
    $Bronze = $PSItem -replace ('Silver', 'Bronze')
    If ($Collection -contains $Bronze) { "Removing: $Bronze" }
  } # If 'Silver'
} # ForEach-Object

$Collection | ForEach-Object -Process {
  If ($PSItem -match 'Gold') {
    $Silver = $PSItem -replace ('Gold', 'Silver')
    $Bronze = $PSItem -replace ('Gold', 'Bronze')
    If     ($Collection -contains $Silver) { "Removing: $Silver" }
    ElseIf ($Collection -contains $Bronze) { "Removing: $Bronze" }
  } # If 'Gold'
} # ForEach-Object
```

Output:

```
Removing: Invitational.Bronze.txt
Removing: Olympics.Bronze.txt
Removing: Invitational.Silver.txt
```

Comment: HA!!! splitting on Silver and gold. Pure genius. Simple, elegant and Grand!